# CloudKit for Online Storage

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8, online-storage

I need to know how to add data on the CloudKit database.

I know that CloudKit has no server side logic (So how do I then see what of my data is on CloudKit public database ?)

How do I then save (pictures, videos, files etc.) to the public database. So that all the other users can download this content on their iPad on a later stage.

I know files will be stored as a CKAsset and can't be more than 250 mb.

I've read up on CloudKit and CKAsset Class Reference from Apple, but I'm still not sure how to use CloudKit. [CKAsset Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/prerelease/mac/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKAsset_class/index.html)

Is there a better way to implement online storage in IOS 8 ?[CloudKit Storage Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/cloudkit-storage/)

Comment: FWIW ..... save yourself a world of time and just use parse.com or another bAAs.

Comment: Hey thanks for the fast help. Ive checked out the pars.com and see that it can be used for online database , and looks very simple to use.

Comment: it couldn't be simpler, hope it helps.  everything is moving to "baas" such as parse, so, I guess we have to move also

Comment: Listen Thanx for all the advise i got a great tutorial about using parse and downloading,uploading and deleting data. http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-save-data-parse-cloud-tutorial/

Comment: Now i wanna know how do i save the data that is downloaded in the app bundle so that i don't need to download every time i run the app. If you do have a nice tutorial it will help a lot. Thanx

Comment: hi Joe thanx for all the help so far I've been playing around with parse and its very simple to use. I've done a tutorial that helps me  add users and validate their email. Now I need to know if you could push me in the right direction on emailing the users. if they forgot their password and they need to retrieve their password through an email. I would ask a separate question for this and i will but i don't have enough reputation points on Stack Overflow to ask more questions for 2 more days. Thanx for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading the [CloudKitAtlas sample code](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/PRERELEASE/IOS/samplecode/CloudAtlas/Introduction/Intro.html). You can also use developer.icloud.com to see what's in your iCloud store.